# Processing several pictures from camera dealing with heap memory

Tags: android

I want to process several pictures from the camera and compute some operations on each.
Currently I'm scaling down every image in the cameras JPEG callback to hold each in the heap memory at runtime, but since this doesn't scale that good (apparently) I'm in need of a proper solution. Also the image operations need to be fast and I want to avoid writing each image onto SD as long as possible. After doing my operations I don't need the images anymore.

I was thinking of referencing every image in a list of SoftReferenes, but since I won't be notified before  the GC is deleting a reference (so that I could save this particular image on to SD) this doesn't seem to be an option.

Any hints or tips are welcome.

Comment: How many images at a time that you are loading? Can you process it one by one or you have to have all of them together in order to process it? What kind of processing are you doing?

Comment: I'm processing between 4 and 9 images from the camera. Unfortunately I can't separate the process, I need all images at the same time. I'm doing some mathematical calculations on the sum of all the images.